# SOAPAction header does not match the service

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap

During integration with external system I had to switch from one environment to another. This means to change the URL where wsdl is placed and to put user credentials in the header. Looks pretty easy but then I noticed strange behavior. When I try to call service A which is on port 1 then for some reason the SOAPAction header is replaced with the value of service B which is also on port 1. It looks something like:

```
ID: 496
Address: https://domain/env/port
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], password=[test], SOAPAction=["serviceB"], UserName=[test]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><a:aRequest xmlns:a="http://a/namespace/">...
```

Then the response is of course that the unexpected request object has been passed. 
What is more strange that sometimes the SOAPAction header is ok, the service which has been called is ok and the request object is ok but the response still says that it expected different request object because for some reason server called other service that I wanted to call.

So my question is: in what way the SAOPAction value is set - is it taken from generated class from `@WebMethod(action = "serviceA")` or is it generated during reading wsdl file? I need to figure it out if the problem is on my side or on the external server side.

EDIT:
I noticed that: when I call serviceA for the first time then SOAPAction header is set to operation serviceB. Then I call the second time the serviceA and the response code is 200. Then I call serviceB for the first time and the SOAPAction header is set to serviceA. When I call serviceB the second time then the response code is 200. So it looks like there is some kind of caching (?!)...

EDIT:
Ok, so it looks like that: I am creating Port with Service class from javax.xml.ws package with `Service myservice = Service.create(serviceName)` method and `myservice.getPort(MySpecifiedPort.class)`. I annotate this method with `@Produces` and if I need this Port then I inject it with `@Inject` annotation. Sometimes I receive (I think) the instance from the pool. And if that happen then the SOAPAction is set to the value from the previous call. But why does this happend? Shouldn't SOAPAction be set as new every time I call WS? Whis does it look like to be cached somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I hope I found the solution. The problem was that in order to set http headers with credentials I did:

```
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) bp.getRequestContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new HashMap<>();
}
headers.put("UserName", Collections.singletonList(configuration.getProperty(API_USERNAME)));
headers.put("password", Collections.singletonList(configuration.getProperty(API_PASSWORD)));
bp.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

For some reason this causes the problem and SOAPAction header has been sometimes remembered from the previous call. The solution is to implement SOAPHandler

```
class CredentialsHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

   private Configuration configuration;

   public CredentialsHandler(Configuration configuration) {
       this.configuration = configuration;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
       try {
           Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
           headers.put("UserName", Collections.singletonList(configuration.getProperty(API_USERNAME)));
           headers.put("password", Collections.singletonList(configuration.getProperty(API_PASSWORD)));
           context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
       } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Configuration exception");
       }

       return true;
   }
}
```

And in the place where my headers were added put the following line of code:

```
bp.getBinding().setHandlerChain(Collections.<Handler>singletonList(new CredentialsHandler(configuration)));
```